# How to fetch response using okHttpClient?

Tags: android, response, okhttp

usually I use volley to send and fetch data from server but in my one activity I have used okHttpClient to send data and receive from sever. I am able to send and receive data from server but I am not able to separate as per fields.

Below is my code

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mail sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        description.setText(" ");
                        txt_picture_preview.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                        selecttypedec.setSelection(0);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                        Log.d("TAG", "response of image: " + response.body().string());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

But it throws me error i.e.  "org.json.JSON Exception : End of input at character 0 at"

Please help me how can I get data field wise.[image: Response from server]

This is my response. Please help.

> {"user_detail":{"id":110,"user_id":53,"address_type":"H","status":"A","house_number":"2","street_number":"zuiderdijk","city":"wetteren","country":"Belgium","postal_code":"9230","latitude":"","longitude":"","created_at":"2017-11-13
>   11:15:53","updated_at":"2017-11-29
>   10:29:35","admin_id":2,"admin_status":"A","user":{"id":53,"first_name":"chitra","last_name":"solanki","email":"schitralekha@deaninfotech.com","mobile":null,"sms_alternate_number":"1234567890","postal_code":null,"language":"fr","otp":null,"status":"A","gcm_id":null,"imei_number":"356554060835242","sms_status":"n","api_token":"$2y$10$QKOHH7GYJc/eVT4BGqq5U.0hEp8iVZh0Ybep9yySWjlM6SYRvG0gC","created_at":"2017-11-13
>   11:12:06","updated_at":"2017-11-29 10:29:35"}},"success":"Current
>   active location updated successfully!"}

Comment: could you post entire response.body() trace?

Comment: check updated post @rajanks

Comment: Make sure you are getting valid response from server ? and its in json format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response.body().string());
        JSONObject user_detail= jsonObject.getJSONObject("user_detail");

        Log.e("id",user_detail.getString("id"));
        Log.e("user_id",user_detail.getString("user_id"));
        Log.e("address_type",user_detail.getString("address_type"));
        Log.e("status",user_detail.getString("status"));
        Log.e("house_number",user_detail.getString("house_number"));
        Log.e("street_number",user_detail.getString("street_number"));
        Log.e("city",user_detail.getString("city"));
        Log.e("country",user_detail.getString("country"));
        Log.e("postal_code",user_detail.getString("postal_code"));
        Log.e("latitude",user_detail.getString("latitude"));
        Log.e("longitude",user_detail.getString("longitude"));
        Log.e("created_at",user_detail.getString("created_at"));
        Log.e("updated_at",user_detail.getString("updated_at"));
        Log.e("admin_id",user_detail.getString("admin_id"));
        Log.e("admin_status",user_detail.getString("admin_status"));

        JSONObject user= user_detail.getJSONObject("user");
        Log.e("id",user.getString("id"));
        Log.e("first_name",user.getString("first_name"));
        Log.e("last_name",user.getString("last_name"));
        Log.e("email",user.getString("email"));
        Log.e("mobile",user.getString("mobile"));
        Log.e("sms_alternate_number",user.getString("sms_alternate_number"));
        Log.e("postal_code",user.getString("postal_code"));
        Log.e("language",user.getString("language"));
        Log.e("otp",user.getString("otp"));
        Log.e("status",user.getString("status"));
        Log.e("gcm_id",user.getString("gcm_id"));
        Log.e("imei_number",user.getString("imei_number"));
        Log.e("sms_status",user.getString("sms_status"));
        Log.e("api_token",user.getString("api_token"));
        Log.e("created_at",user.getString("created_at"));
        Log.e("updated_at",user.getString("updated_at"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to make a model class (see [references here](https://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Model-data-POJO-classes/486757/555446-4.html)).

Now in class declare all fields which are coming in Json form in response. Which are as: id, user_id, status, address_type, etc...

Now you can access that Json as:

```
  JSONObject userdetailObject = jsonObject.getJsonObject("user_detail");
  ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
  model.setId(userdetailObject.getString("I'd");
 Model.serUserId(userdetailObject.getString("user_id");
```

In this way you got access to whole entities in variable with "model object" like we did in the Volley POJO class.

Comment: What error and where can you please elaborate to me??...so that I can solve that

Comment: I am using this approach to fetch response from okHttpClient but it shows me json exception as I described in post.

Comment: Heyyy can you please log cat for this line "Log.d("TAG", "response of image: " + response.body().string()); 
"

Comment: Yes, this provides me whole response but when I use  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());  it throws error

Comment: Can you please share your webservice, which you are hitting so that i can check, Dont Worry it would be in privacy. Here is my mail id ankitpatidar030@gmail.com